# R Indexing, Matrix multiplication

Tags: r, memory, matrix, memory-management, matrix-multiplication

I seem to have a misunderstanding about memory usage when using a subset of a matrix in R.  I came across when I tried to program a cross validation function, but I think the problem is more general.  I have cooked up a small example below.

```
# parameters
n <- 1e6 # the real data are much bigger, but this will do
m <- 50
nfolds <- 10
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*m,0,1),nrow=n,ncol=m)
y <- rnorm(n,0,1)
mse <- rep(0,nfolds)
foldid <- sample(rep(seq(nfolds), length = n))

# produces big spikes in memory
for (i in (1:nfolds)) {
  which <- foldid == i
  xpx <- crossprod(X[!which,])
  xpy <- crossprod(X[!which,],y[!which])
  b <- solve(xpx,xpy)
  mse[i] <- mean((y[which] - X[which,] %*% b)**2)
}

# does not produce spikes in memory usage
for (i in (1:nfolds)) {
  xpx <- crossprod(X)
  xpy <- crossprod(X,y)
  b <- solve(xpx,xpy)
  mse[i] <- mean((y - X %*% b)**2)
}
```

I don't understand why the first loop produces big upward spikes in memory usage, whereas the second loop doesn't although a strictly larger matrix is multiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare the first lines withing the loops.

First, the simple `crossprod`:

```
xpx <- crossprod(X)
```

Without subsetting, you work with matrices `X` (already existing 400 MB) and `xpx` (small).

Second, with subsetting:

```
xpx <- crossprod(X[!which,])
```

Here you work with `X`, temporary matrix `X[!which,]`, and `xpx`. The additional matrix `X[!which,]` requires additional 360 MB of memory.

```
object.size(X[!which,])
# 360000200 bytes
```

R has relatively poor memory managment, so the temporary matrix may not be discarded for some time.